# SQL Server - Transpose Date from One Table To Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

Can't figure out how to transpose data from one table to another. Do I use a cursor?
Sample Data:

```
Build Part SN  DateShipped
A     1    123 2017-01-01
A     2    234 2017-02-02
A     3    345 2017-03-03
B     1    987 2017-01-01
B     2    876 2017-02-02
B     3    765 2017-03-03
```

Desired Result:

```
Build Part1SN Part1Ship  Part2SN Part2Ship  Part3SN Part3Ship
A     123     2017-01-01 234     2017-02-02 345     2017-03-03
B     987     2017-01-01 876     2017-02-02 765     2017-03-03
```

Comment: You can do it using `PIVOT`, if supported by the RDBMS you are using, or *conditional aggregation*. There are plenty of examples here in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mixing data types (date & int) in the Pivot, I'll give a working example of a dynamic Pivot.  Date note of what we are doing within the Cross Apply.

I'm also assuming Part is sequential within build, otherwise we would need to apply/nest a Row_Number()

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select A.Build
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat(''Part'',A.Part,''SN''),  concat('''',A.SN))
                             ,(concat(''Ship'',A.Part,''Ship''),concat('''',A.DateShipped))
                     ) B (Item,Value)
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select ','+QuoteName(concat('Part',Part,'SN')) 
                                                     +','+QuoteName(concat('Ship',Part,'Ship')) 
                                               From (Select Distinct Part From YourTable ) A  
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL)
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Generated SQL Looks Like This**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select A.Build
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat('Part',A.Part,'SN'),  concat('',A.SN))
                             ,(concat('Ship',A.Part,'Ship'),concat('',A.DateShipped))
                     ) B (Item,Value)
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in ([Part1SN],[Ship1Ship],[Part2SN],[Ship2Ship],[Part3SN],[Ship3Ship]) ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Build,
max(case Part when 1 then SN end)   'Part1SN', max(case Part when 1 then DateShipped end) 'Part1Ship',
max(case Part when 2 then SN end)   'Part2SN', max(case Part when 2 then DateShipped end) 'Part2Ship',
max(case Part when 3 then SN end)   'Part3SN', max(case Part when 3 then DateShipped end) 'Part3Ship'
 from TempTable
 group by Build
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try using pivot Table.

For reference follow the below link

https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/